# An exception to the "only one implementation" rule?

Tags: c++, linker, definition

While I was reading the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060730/c-avoid-cpp-files-with-only-an-empty-deconstructor), I had the following question:

Typically, methods are defined in header files (`.hpp` or whatever), and implementation in source files (`.cpp` or whatever).

One of the main reasons it is bad practice to ever include a "source file" (`#include <source_file.cpp>`) is that its methods implementation would then be duplicated, resulting in linking errors.

When one writes:

```
#ifndef BRITNEYSPEARS_HPP
#define BRITNEYSPEARS_HPP

class BritneySpears
{
  public:

    BritneySpears() {}; // Here the constructor has implementation.
};

#endif /* BRITNEYSPEARS_HPP */
```

He is giving the *implementation* of the constructor (here an "empty" implementation, but still).

But why then including this header file multiple times (aka. on different source files) will **not** generate a "duplicate definition" error at link time ?

Comment: Here's another answer about inline and the one definition rule: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908830/isnt-cs-inline-totally-optional/910686#910686

Comment: BTW, BritneySpears has weak linkage in your code. Like in real life :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inline functions are exceptions to the "one definition rule": you are allowed to have identical implementations of them in more than one compilation unit. Functions are inline if they are declared `inline` or implemented inside a class definition.

Comment: Are you sure about this? If I compile this and look at the disassembly, I clearly see a "call" instruction. So, no inlining. Also, I can declare recursive functions in the class definition, include them multiple .cpp files and get no linker error. How can they be inlined? (Might be MS-specific behavior, though)

Comment: @nikie: Even though there might be a call instruction there, the functions are treated differently by the linker, see the link in my answer for details.

Comment: @nikie "inline function" doesn't mean calls to it are inlined. It just means they get special treatment by the linker so multiple definitions of them are allowed in the program. For calls to be inlined this is necessary - because only then, multiple TUs can see the code and not only one TU. But it's not sufficient - the compiler can still use plain call instructions.

Comment: @nikie The compiler is never required to physically inline anything. -

Comment: @all: my mistake. I thought "inline function" meant that calls to the function had to be inlined. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I have to say I use the `inline` keyword more frequently for its linker properties than for performance!

Comment: Thank you very much for the precise explanation ;)

Comment: @AshleysBrain: I use it _only_ for that!

Answer (score 7):

Member functions with implementation inside the class definition are treated as inline functions. Inline functions are exempt from one definition rule.

Specifically when the linker sees two inline functions with the same signature it treats them as if it is the same function and just picks one of them. This can lead [to really weird hard to detect problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aszego/override-atlthrow-with-care).

Answer (score 2):

Because it is an "inline" function.  Inline functions can be included from headers as many times as you like and they don't cause duplicate definition linker errors.

The compiler will also try to bring them inline so, in your example above, the compiler will *try* and eliminate the call to the constructor completely.